# WP_Query and is_page_template() conditional

Tags: wp-query, conditional-tags, wp-reset-query

I have a custom query that goes looks like this:

```
        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'post_status' => 'published', 'paged' => $paged);
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if($wp_query->have_posts()):
            while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
                if(get_post_format()) {
                    $post_format = get_post_format();
                } else {
                    $post_format = 'standard';
                }
                get_template_part('/templates/parts/format', $post_format);
            endwhile;
        endif; ?>
```

Inside post format that I call with `get_template_part('/templates/parts/format', $post_format);` I have conditional `is_page_template()`.

This conditional isn't working. But when I use regular `WP_Query` without resetting the default one it does work. What can i do to make this work?

Comment: If you need to do different things depending on where the template part is included from, then perhaps that template part is doing too much and you need several instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Codex (emphasis mine):

> This Conditional Tag allows you to determine if you are in any page
>   template. Optionally checks if a specific Page Template is being used
>   in a Page. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE
>   or FALSE. ***This tag must be used BEFORE The Loop and does not work
>   inside The Loop*** (see Notes below).
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template

Your `get_template_part()`, and all the code it loads, is inside the Loop, so even if this works for you sometimes you are doing it wrong. I would suggest the solution offered in the Codex:

> The function `get_page_template_slug( $post_id )` will return the slug
>   of the currently assigned page template (or an empty string if no
>   template has been assigned - or false if the `$post_id` does not
>   correspond to an actual page). You can easily use this anywhere (in
>   The Loop, or outside) to determine whether any page has been assigned
>   a page template.
>
> ```
>   // in the loop:
>   if ( get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() ) ){
>      // Yep, this page has a page template
>   }
> ```

That is, alter your code inside `get_template_part('/templates/parts/format', $post_format);` to use `get_page_template_slug( get_the_ID() )`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It turns out that is_page_template() conditional isn't working inside the loop and Codex did point that out. So your answer really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of mistakes here.

Firstly, if you need to check if you have a specific post format, use `has_post_format( $post_format )`. So if you need to something specific for post type video, you will do something like this

```
if ( has_post_format('video')) {
<--show video maybe-->
}
```

Secondly, `standard` is not actually a post format. When no specific format is set, wordpress will assign `Standard` to that post. This is what you will see in the back end in post editor. If you need to exclude all other post types and just display something specific that has no post format assigned to it you will use `false == has_post_format()` For example

```
 if ( false == has_post_format()) {
    <--show post without a post format-->
    }
```

Thirdly, your `is_page_template()` baffles me as I don't know where are you using it.

Just to leave this with you, why don't you create specific `content-postformat.php` templates and just call them normally. `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() )` to get all formats or `get_template_part( 'content', 'video' )` to call a specific format, in this case `video` format.

This is how [twentyfourteen](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen)'s `content.php` looks like. All posts without a post format are diplayd using this template.

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
            endif;

            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                    twentyfourteen_posted_on();

                if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
            ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php
                endif;

                edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php the_tags( '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

That said, and everything put together, your code will look something like this

```
$temp = $wp_query;
    $wp_query = null;
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'post_status' => 'published', 'paged' => $paged);
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($wp_query->have_posts()):
        while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
            if ( false == has_post_format()) {
                <--do something for posts without post format-->
            } else {
                <--do something for posts with post format-->
            }
        endwhile;
    endif; ?>
```

Please also have a look at s-ha-dum's answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, i understand what you mean and you're right, i will use this code from now on

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could be of some assistance